# for loop with mutate only outputs last result

Tags: r, tidyverse, geo

I'm sorry if it's a duplicate, and for the lack of reproducibility, I'd have to link you the files.

What I'm trying to do is this:

I have a data frame with coordinates and names, let's say

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Species, ~lat, ~lon,
  "a",42.92991, 11.875801,
  "b",42.92991, 11.875801,
  "c",43.91278, 3.513611,   
  "d",43.60851, 3.871755,   
  "e",39.24373, 9.120478
)
```

I also have a folder with `tif`rasters, such as

```
files <- list.files(path="~/world/", pattern="*.tif$", full.name=TRUE, all.files=TRUE)
```

Now for each iteration I'd like to:

- create a new column on the data frame with the file name
- insert in that column the extracted value for the corresponding `lat` and `lon`

I've tried using this `for` loop, and while on paper looks just fine, I don't understand why it outputs to `funvar` the last result only. I't like it overwrites the result instead of appending it.

If I use a similar loop with mutate and simpler objects, it appends them, so I'm not sure what the problem could be

```
for(i in files){  
fraster<- raster(i)

fname<-gsub(".*//|[.].*", "", i)

funvar<-dplyr::mutate(fundata, !!fname:= raster::extract(fraster, coordinates(data.frame(lat,lon))))
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put `funvar <- vector()` before the for loop. Then use `funvar <- c(funvar, dplyr::mutate(fundata, ....  coordinates(data.frame(lat,lon))))      )`

Comment: Hi @maydin, by doing like this I'd end up with a vector containing all the variables for every run (that is, not just the column I'd like to add). I could convert it to a data frame, but I'd have `Orc_species`,`Orc_species.1`, `Orc_species.2` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it is a bit of an hack, but works. I explicitly assign the new column to a data frame, like this.
I'm still notsure why `mutate` doesn't do that by itself

```
for(i in files){  
fraster<- raster(i)

fname<-gsub(".*//|[.].*", "", i)

funvar<-dplyr::mutate(fundata, !!fname:= raster::extract(fraster, coordinates(data.frame(lat,lon))))

fundata[fname] <- funvar[[fname]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the info you provide I cannot tell if this will work, but normally you would make a RasterStack and avoid the loop.

```
library(raster)
# NOTE the order of lon, lat`
xy <- cbind(lon, lat)
s <- stack(files)
e <- raster::extract(s, xy)
```

If that is not possible, you can do something like this

```
fundata <- data.frame(xy)
for (f in files){  
    fraster<- raster(f)
    fname <- gsub(".tif$", "", basename(f))
    fundata[[fname]] <- raster::extract(fraster, xy)
}
```